Download speeds on Xbox app on PC are quite slow and sometimes stops
I recently observed that the download speed on Xbox app is quite slow. Sometimes, the download stops completely. However, when I download games from other apps like Steam, I am getting my regular speed, like 140 MB/s.
I have disabled Allow Downloads from other PC (Windows Update -> Advanced Options -> Delivery optimisation) as was written in some forums. But that did NOT seem to have solved the problem.
I have tried the following steps :-

Delivery Optimisation - enabling download from multiple PC
Disabling antivirus
Turning off Real time protection
Checking other Internet connections
Re-instaiing the entire Windows
Downloading latest drivers
Downloading latest Windows updates
Updating Xbox and MS Store to the latest version
Delivery Optimisation -Setting download speed in background and foreground to max
Using the Xbox Diagnostics in Xbox PC App - Support
Using the DNS=8.8.8.8 and Alternate DNS= 8.8.4.4

Nothing works.


Please help.

Anything else, even as small as restarting the PC or router? Has the PC been moved across a long distance, e.g. city/state/country without getting the DNS cache cleared so it can rebuild paths to servers? The servers it's downloading from are also an important part, as if they're just plain crap you're not going to get much - if any - better. Steam's servers are generally great because they use Akamai's CDN which is worldwide and seems to have lots of bandwidth to throw around. Steam client also finds the nearest CDN itself.

Restarting PC or Router didnt work. Also, the speed is extremely extremely slow in the Xbox app. The PC is at the same place for downloading from Steam and Xbox. And I have observed that most Microsoft Games are slow to download, like Call of Duty, Gears of War. The 3rd party games download okay (8-9 MB/s)

Update- Turns out, even 3rd party updates are not downloading properly

There's some suggestions on the XBox support page including that it's possible there's a hardware issue anywhere between your PC and the internet. The most relevant suggestion is likely changing the DNS server; Google Public DNS is one of a handful of options. This is unlikely to do much considering the issue seems to be MS servers, but it shouldn't hurt to try it. If you do so it would be best to also clear/flush the DNS cache.

There are some potentially-relevant settings like Delivery Optimization -> Advanced has settings for bandwidth limit, and mentions that it automatically optimizes the bandwidth used for Windows and app updates and other MS products. No idea if this includes the Xbox app, but it seems implied as that's obviously an MS product. Totally possible there's more that could be done that IDK about, as I'm no expert.

@l3l_aze I have updated my post with the steps that I had previously taken. Also, hardware error could have caused problems for all apps, not limited toXbox

Yeah, only a theory it could be a hardware issue, but unlikely. Found "limit reservable bandwidth" which may be relevant, but as this says and others elaborate: this is during high-priority downloads, and 100% of the bandwidth is available otherwise. Don't have gpedit.msc even while logged as admin, but the much shorter manual RegEdit directions "worked" (didn't keep the changes as I don't have this issue). Lots of older issues in the opposite direction with Delivery Optimization eating bandwidth/RAM, may be an over-correction.
